# fit background image in to a dynamic div

Tags: css, dynamic, html, background-image

i have a background image (700x500px) and i want to fill wit it a dynamic div. in this example the div is only 20px but it can have a height over 500px.

```
<div style="background-image:url('background.jpg');width:710px">
some content some content
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, what's the question?

Answer (score 1):

Using standard CSS you can't just fit a background image. But you can use an image tag in a div and make it resize. And then use your content in front of it, so the image will be used as a background.

You can find more details, css usage and an example page here :
http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_stretch_background_image.cfm

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `background-size: cover;` to your style attribute